# Binomial Sum Formula

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I can't find a good closed form expression for this, $\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k}\right]$, where n is the variable, and m is a fixed constant, to be included in the formula. :( Can someone provide me with a formula?

Comment: What have you done thus far toward a partial solution?

Comment: This is [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: @Lucian: more precisely, this can be rewritten to one side of the  Vandermonde's identity; OP is asking about the expression at the other side of it (which of course is easy to obtain from your link).

Comment: @TerraHyde: Although I'd have no difficulty with this problem, I would find it very hard to formulate a _partial_ solution. Once you've got the idea, it is bang on.